# iframe scroll event listen in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, svg, scroll

All,

I have two images (SVG) which I want to 'fixed position' in an iframe. Unfortunately the CSS property of fixed position does not work here, so am trying to accomplish this with js.

Here is the code which listens to the scroll movement of the iframe which I use to move the images (SVG) in the iframe. Unfortunately, this is not working in Chrome. Any guidance please.

`window.onload = function () {
    var f = document.getElementById ("iframe_id").contentWindow;
        frm.onscroll = movef;
    }`

```
function movef (evt) {
    alert ("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The document lang differs slightly in chrome.
contentWindow would be contentDocument in chrome